# Xamarin.Forms Android System.ObjectModel could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I create the first Xamarin.Forms project using Visual Studio 2017.

The error is `The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.`. The dll `System.ObjectModel.dll` is existing in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades` however it shows Yellow triangle on References.

Replaced by the another dll in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades` to remove Yellow triangle.

However got another error when compiling:

> CS1703    Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate
>   references.   App2.Android    C:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\App2\App2\App2.Android\CSC  1   Active

Any idea pls?

Comment: You can open the project file in notepad and remove one of the invalid reference. After that reload the project,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

- Removed the current DLL
- Reinstall the package via Nuget